# Trying to compile Assembly + C++ with MinGW: ccqKAvXJ.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `GetMagicNumber'

Tags: c++, hyperlink, compilation, .net-assembly

I have this simple sample:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" int GetMagicNumber();

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "The magic number is: " << GetMagicNumber();
    return 0;
}
```

functions.s:

```
.section .text

.global GetMagicNumber

GetMagicNumber:
    movl $42, %eax
    ret
```

and build.bat:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\as functions.s -o functions.o
C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\g++ functions.o main.cpp -o MagicNumber.exe
```

or

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\gcc functions.s main.cpp -lstdc++ -o MagicNumber.exe
```

When I try to compile with MinGW 4.8. I get:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\gcc functions.s main.cpp -lstdc++ -o MagicNumber.exe
C:\Users\...\Local\Temp\ccqKAvXJ.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `GetMagicNumber'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've read a few tutorials and I watched videos and I still cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Why do I get that undefined reference error?

Comment: the order of object files matters.

Comment: I changed the order of .o and .cpp but I still get the same error. My goal is to add NEON and SSE2 optimized functions to my code. I tried Visual Studio and it works. Then I tried to add external assembly files in Qt Creator and I couldn't get them to link. That's why I'm trying something very simple. That example is basically what this guy does in his video tutorial and it works: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jR6BnVGpAe0&list=PLKK11Ligqiti8g3gWRtMjMgf1KoKDOvME

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers.

Answer (score 1):

External scope *C* symbols have a leading underscore, so try:

```
.section .text

.global _GetMagicNumber

_GetMagicNumber:
    movl $42, %eax
    ret
```

**EDIT** if you want to make the code more platform-agnostic, I use the following macro, where the assembler file has a `.S` extension which is processed by the C compiler, allowing the pre-processor to play along:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#define NAME(name) _##name
#else
#define NAME(name) name
#endif

.globl NAME(GetMagicNumber);
NAME(GetMagicNumber):
    ...
```

(see an example [here](https://github.com/trojanfoe/ChessCore/blob/master/src/AsmX86.S)).

Comment: Yes, you are right! I did that it works. Thank you! But I specifically installed Linux to try it on Linux and gcc 4.6 would compile the code without the underscores. Actually if I put the underscore, the code would not be compiled. So on MinGW I need to put the underscore and on Linux I have to remove it. Why is that so? I am totally confused now.

Comment: Different platforms have different name mangling conventions. Windows has the leading underscore for the `cdecl` calling convention, and a different convention for `stdcall`.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Yeah, true.  I don't use GNU assembler under Windows, preferring to use a separate Microsoft-compatible assembler source file (`.asm`).